# 3 or more *consecutive* layout passes to prepare to be shown. Error

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, warnings, nspopover

When I open an NSPopover I am getting the following error:

```
WARNING: <NSPopover: 0x618000120780> needed 3 or more *consecutive* layout
passes to prepare to be shown. Verify that nothing in your view hierarchy
is aggressively dirtying layout during layout, as this will likely
cause problems elsewhere.
```

This has only just started appearing in a recent build and I can not find what is causing it.  I have removed all prep code before the popover is shown so it basically calls:

```
- (IBAction)addClicked:(id)sender {

[[self addPopover] showRelativeToRect:[sender bounds] ofView:sender preferredEdge:NSMaxYEdge];

}
```

I have removed all constraints from the window in IB too.  So I shouldn't be doing anything during layout that requires a repaint.

Searching the web comes up with very little info, what I could find anyway.  My popover is used for a form input so has 4 NSTextFields an NSOutlineView and an NSImage.  It also creates a hidden WebView which is not visible to the user and used for server processing.

OSX 10.7+

Any ideas?
Thanks
Geoff

Comment: Fixed it.  if you ever get this error, I got rid of it by selecting the view effects inspector in IB and put a checkmark next to view (for this entire popup) for the Core Animation Layer.  Now I can have square buttons with template images and no obscure warning.

Comment: You should probably post that as an answer.

Comment: Thanks.  Done that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if you ever get this error, I removed it by selecting the view effects inspector in IB and put a checkmark next to view (the entire popup view) for the Core Animation Layer. Now I can have square buttons with template images and no obscure warning.